# sql, c , select two rows with highest timestamp and group by two cols

Tags: sql, select

I asked the same question, but did not get final answer, so, trying here again. 
there are two types of quotes, Repo Rate or Last Price, I want to select the repo rate with highest datetime, AND Last price with highest datetime from two tables.
Here is an answer which I got help from my initial posting, but I need two records (repo and last price) if both exists. can anyone please help by changing the query below: many thanks!!

```
SELECT  QuoteObservations.id, 
        QuoteObservations.value, 
        QuoteObservations.quotePointId,
        max(QuoteObservations.asOfTime) as asOfTime, 
        QuoteObservations.dataProviderId,
        QuotePoints.quoteType 
FROM    QuoteObservations
INNER JOIN
        QuotePoints 
ON      QuoteObservations.quotePointId = QuotePoints.id 
WHERE   QuotePoints.quoteType in (1,2)
group by 
        QuoteObservations.id, 
        QuoteObservations.value, 
        QuoteObservations.quotePointId,
        QuoteObservations.dataProviderId, 
        QuotePoints.quoteType;
```

Comment: Instead of re-asking the question, perhaps you should edit your original question?

Comment: Agree with the above two comments.  It would be more respectful to answer your previous question's comments and give feedback on the answers there.

Comment: I did edit question, and replied to the comment, and 4 days passed, seems people are busy. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for two rows to be returned.  The following SQL will accomplish what you describe:

```
SELECT TOP(1) QuoteObservations.id, 
    QuoteObservations.value, 
    QuoteObservations.quotePointId,
    QuoteObservations.asOfTime, 
    QuoteObservations.dataProviderId,
    QuotePoints.quoteType 
FROM    QuoteObservations
INNER JOIN QuotePoints 
ON      QuoteObservations.quotePointId = QuotePoints.id 
WHERE   QuotePoints.quoteType = 1 -- Get most recent row for quoteType 1
ORDER BY QuoteObservations.asOfTime DESC

UNION ALL 

SELECT TOP(1) QuoteObservations.id, 
    QuoteObservations.value, 
    QuoteObservations.quotePointId,
    QuoteObservations.asOfTime, 
    QuoteObservations.dataProviderId,
    QuotePoints.quoteType 
FROM    QuoteObservations
INNER JOIN QuotePoints 
ON      QuoteObservations.quotePointId = QuotePoints.id 
WHERE   QuotePoints.quoteType = 2 -- Get most recent row for quoteType 2
ORDER BY QuoteObservations.asOfTime DESC
```